# Python3 How to implement time value of money in a mortgage scenario

Tags: python-3.x, function, user-input

I want to implement a function to calculate mortgages. It takes the user input such as the loan amount, duration of the loan, the frequency of payment in a year, and the annualized interest rate. After the necessary input, the function will generate an output to show the user the total interest needed to pay after the end of the period of the loan, and the total amount to pay (total loan interest + loan amount).

This is what I have done:

```
def get_mortgage_cashflows():
    
    loan_amount = float(input('Enter mortgage loan amount: '))
    loan_period = float(input('Enter the number of period in years: '))
    loan_frequency = int(input('Enter the number of payment per year: '))
    loan_interest = float(input('Enter the annual interest rate: '))
    loan_total_interest = (loan_amount * (1 + (loan_interest / 100) / loan_frequency) ** loan_period) - loan_amount
    loan_total_amount = loan_amount + loan_total_interest
    
    return loan_total_interest, loan_total_amount

total_interest, total_amount = get_mortgage_cashflows()

print('total interest: ', total_interest)
print('total payment amount: ', total_amount)
```

However, there seems to be an error as there is no output generated.

A sample test case from my class activities:

```
Mortgage loan: $1,000,000 

Period: 10 years

Frequency: Annual repayment

Annualized interest rate: 1.5%
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I get:

```
Enter mortgage loan amount: >? 1000000
Enter the number of period in years: >? 10
Enter the number of payment per year: >? 1
Enter the annual interest rate: >? 1.5
total interest:  160540.82502514892
total payment amount:  1160540.825025149
```

Can you try again to run the code you gave us and confirm you still have the issue ?